# How to calculate proton affinities for each atom in a molecule using DFT in gaussian?

Tags: density-functional-theory, gaussian

I want to calculate the proton affinities for each atom of my molecule using DFT in gaussian.
For a conjugated organic system that contains an heteroatome one or more...etc composed of about 20 atoms in a ch2cl2 solvent.
Is it something to do with thermochemistry for example enthalpies values . Or is there a way to obtain the values of affinities directly from a keyword in gaussian

Comment: The question is too vague. Please specify (1) the type of the molecule, e.g. organic molecule, inorganic molecule without metals, or metal complex; (2) whether you want to do the calculation in solution or vacuum; (3) how large the molecule is; (4) whether the molecule has significantly charged atoms (molecules with strongly anionic atoms need different levels of theory than molecules without them); (5) what is the desired level of accuracy (~10 kcal/mol? ~3 kcal/mol? ~1 kcal/mol?). Also, do you already know how to calculate reaction energies? If yes, the answer can be considerably shorter.

Comment: @wzkchem5 I thought maybe  there is a classical way to do it for any system.

Comment: I just checked the definition of proton affinity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_affinity. It appears that the proton affinity is only defined in the gas phase. So either you must calculate the proton affinity in the gas phase, or you calculate something in CH2Cl2 that is not called proton affinity. In other words, the quantity that you asked for cannot be calculated because it is not defined.